# Why are my characters overlapping?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

As a test of what's going wrong with a longer LaTeX file I've written, here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[left] {A} -- (1,1) node[right] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I then run this with `latex test.tex` and `dvipng test.dvi -o output.png` and I'm ending up with the TikZ part all overlapping:

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.SE. Presumably, dvipng isn't able to interpret all the \special instructions produced by TikZ (the DVI format can't handle advanced graphics stuff natively, only rules and character boxes). It gives a bunch of warnings here. If you compile with pdflatex, you should see a better result. :-)

Comment: `dvipng` doesn't understand the `\special` commands used by TikZ. If you try to view the dvi file with `xdvi` you will see the same overlapping.

Comment: If you want to create images from such LaTeX documents, I recommend using pdflatex/xelatex for compilation and converting the resulting PDF file with ImageMagick to PNG format